# How to solve com.google.gsm:play-service version compatibility issue? While map activity is added this message is displayed:

Tags: android, google-play-services

All com.google.android.gms libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 15.0.4, 15.0.1. Examples include com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:15.0.4 and com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1 less... (Ctrl+F1) 
There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your targetSdkVersion.)

Comment: Seems like the question is answering itself: All com.google.android.gms libraries must use the exact same version specification.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42374151/all-com-android-support-libraries-must-use-the-exact-same-version-specification)

Comment: yep SuryaKant Bharti, you are right, but there is an unknown library that uses the older/newer version, how to identify that? or how to override other so that the map activity gets executed?
Thanks for time....

Comment: Will ignoring the inspection work for many devices?

Comment: The requirement all Google Play services libraries are at the same version is no longer true. See https://developers.google.com/android/guides/versioning

What version of Android Studio are you using? This is likely due to using an older AS which still enforced this out-of-date lint rule.